# Parts of speech or participial construction (insertion of "palm face up")

Tags: participial-phrases

People don’t usually think of touch as a temporal
phenomenon, but it is every bit as time-based as it is spatial.
You can carry out an experiment to see for yourself. Ask a
friend to cup his hand, **palm face up**, and close his eyes. Place
a small ordinary object in his palm ― a ring, an eraser,
anything will do ― and ask him to identify it without moving
any part of his hand.

One idea: palm face(two word noun) + being(present participle) + up => palm face (being) up

Another idea: palm(noun) + face up(adverb) => palm face up = with his palm faced up

**Research**

Adverb
face-up (not comparable)

In a position with the face upwards.
The cards must be dealt faceup(sic)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/face-up

Comment: Why is _face_ involved here? The palm is part of the hand, not the head. Simply saying _palm up_ is sufficient; it's the opposite of _palm down_, and that's the idea.

Comment: I think it's because the writer wanted to emphasize "your palm should face up".

Comment: Wouldn't 'palm facing up' be better?

Comment: But pragmatically, when I tell someone, “Close your eyes and hold out your hands” they never have their palms facing down.

Comment: That's because that phrase is an invitation to receive a treat in your hand, so the palm is up, ready to receive it. Not "facing up", but just up. Palms don't have a face. If you want them to put their palms down, say _Close your eyes and hold out your hands, palms down._

Comment: "an invitation to receive a treat in your hand" It's a jolly jape to put a slightly warm sausage in someones' hand.

Comment: What about just "palm being up"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct understanding is palm **[face up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/face+up)**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "face up" is an adverb here ? and palm face up is not a participial construction but an "insertion"

Comment: Palm face up is an adverbial phrase, modifying the verb **cup**, describing how he is to place his hand. You can tell this because it is set off by commas.

Comment: Thx. Do you think "with his palm faced up" is also possible? something like "with his eyes closed"

Comment: No, you really can't. Hands are not "faced up".

Comment: Not hand but "palm" could be "faced up"? or "with his palm face up"? Just wonder if I can make "with" phrase here

Comment: No, palms can't be _faced up_. But if you want to speak English as if they can, go ahead; nobody can stop you. Some people will understand you, and that's par.